# How to find the bounds of a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to show that $x_n = {1\over n+1} + {1\over n+2} + … + {1\over2n}$ is bounded. However, I haven’t seen a bounding problem with a sequence like this, so I’m a little unsure where to start. I can obviously figure out a lower bound, but a higher bound is escaping me right now.

Comment: How many terms are there and which term is the maximum?

Comment: There would be n terms, and the largest term would be 1/n+1.

Comment: Doesn't that answer the question already?

Answer (score 1):

Why not $x_n<\underbrace{\frac{1}{n}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n}}_{n\text{ terms}}=1$?

Comment: And similarly, why not $x_n>\underbrace{\frac{1}{2n}+\cdots +\frac{1}{2n}}_{n\text{ terms}}=\frac{1}{2}$?

Answer (score 0):

Start with
$$ n < n+1 < n+2 < \cdots < 2n  $$
and take reciprocals.
$$  \frac{1}{n} > \frac{1}{n+1} > \frac{1}{n+2} > \cdots > \frac{1}{2n}  \text{.}  $$
In particular, $1/n$ is greater than each other fraction in this list.  So
$$  1 = n \cdot \frac{1}{n} > \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n} = x_n  \text{.}  $$